# How can I create controller routes in Pylons for multi-part IDs?

Tags: python, rest, routes, pylons

By default the RESTful controller in Pylons supports single-part IDs for objects. This works for some kinds of objects, but my domain model has a set of objects that have composite identifiers, and I'd like to be able to build good URLs for those as well.

This is what is currently supported:

```
GET /advanis/saas/projects/id: Show a specific item
```

This is what I want:

```
GET /advanis/saas/projects/client/key: Show a specific item
```

How can I configure my routing to support this?

Comment: Are you creating your routes with `map.resource()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your routes can have as many dynamic parts as you need. [Read about route parts here](http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/urls-routing-and-dispatch.html#route-parts).

Quick example:

In `config/routing.py`:

```
map.connect('specific_key', '/advanis/saas/projects/{client}/{key}', 
            controller='mycontroller',
            action='item')
```

In `controllers/mycontroller.py`:

```
def item(self, client, key):
    ...
```

Comment: `:something` is deprecated in favour of `{something}`

Comment: Also note that dynamic parts of a route don't have to be at the end. In one of my current projects I use `map.connect('galleries', '/company/{company_id:\d+}/galleries', controller='galleries', action='index')` or even more general `map.connect('/company/{company_id:\d+}/{controller}/{id}/{action}')` because all the actions depend on the chosen company (client). `:\d+` means that the ID is numeric (other IDs won't be matched).